# How to check Lucene version in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-framework2, zend-search-lucene

My java code in eclipse 4.2 is generating an index using lucene 2.9.1. I am using Zend framework 1.12.20 with PHP 7.1 at front end to do search and getting below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception: Unsupported segments file format in C:\xampp1\php\pear\Zend\Search\Lucene.php:422 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp1\php\pear\Zend\Search\Lucene.php(570): Zend_Search_Lucene->_readSegmentsFile()

What is causing the problem?

How can I check which lucene version is used in Zend framework 1.12.20?

Answer (score 0):

From Zend documentation:

> Zend_Search_Lucene was derived from the Apache Lucene project. The currently (starting from ZF 1.6) supported Lucene index format versions are **1.4 - 2.3**